# Is it true that $|a^{\alpha} - b^{\alpha}| \leq |a-b|^{\alpha}$?

Tags: inequality

I am currently reading some papers that seem to use the fact that $$|a^{\alpha} - b^{\alpha}| \leq |a-b|^{\alpha},$$ for $-1< \alpha < 0$ and $a,b$ in the upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$. Is this true or not? I want to use differentiation to prove this, but I don't know how to deal with this situation in the complex case. Any comments?

Comment: How are you defining $a^{\alpha}$?

Comment: Well, you got to be careful with branch cuts in the complex case, at any rate.

Comment: Just the principal branch.

Comment: Why did you change your question?

Comment: I realise that I made some mistakes in my previous work and that was not what I want.

Comment: You should ask another question for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the new version of the problem, with $-1 < \alpha < 0$, consider $a = 1$, $b = -1$.  We have 
$$ \left| \dfrac{1^{-1} - (-1)^{-1}}{(1 - (-1))^{-1}}\right| = 4$$
so for $\alpha \to -1+$ with $b \to -1$ and $a \to +1$ in the upper half plane, 
$$ \dfrac{|a^\alpha - b^\alpha|}{|a - b|^\alpha} = 
\left| \dfrac{a^\alpha - b^\alpha}{(a-b)^\alpha}\right| \to 4$$
For example, with $b = -1 + i/10$, $a = 1 + i/10$, $\alpha = -9/10$, 
$$\dfrac{|a^\alpha - b^\alpha|}{|a - b|^\alpha} \approx 3.6 > 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Edit: OP originally asked if the inequality is true for $\alpha\in(0,1)$. It is true if $\alpha\in(0,1)$. The inequality is equivalent to
$$ |x^\alpha-1|\le|x-1|^\alpha. $$
W.L.OG, let $x\ge 1$. Define
$$ f(x)=(x^\alpha-1)-(x-1)^\alpha, x\in[1,\infty). $$
Then
$$ f'(x)=\alpha [x^{\alpha-1}-(x-1)^{\alpha-1}]=\alpha\left[\frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}-\frac{1}{(x-1)^{1-\alpha}}\right]. $$
Noting that $x>x-1>0$ implies $\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{x-1}$, we have $f'(x)<0$ since $1-\alpha>0$. This implies that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. So for $x\ge1$, we have $f(x)\le f(0)=0$ or
$$ |x^\alpha-1|\le|x-1|^\alpha. $$

Comment: Makes sense for real $x$ but what about complex $x$?

Comment: @nayrb, it is a good question. I believe it is true.

Comment: Why can we assume WLOG $x \geq 1$? Also, OP edited so now $-1 < \alpha <0$.

Comment: @user46944, I don't know why OP changed the problem.

Comment: @xpaul But in your original solution, why could you assume $x \geq 1$?

Comment: Let $a \geq b$, then $x=a/b\geq 1$.

Comment: @nayrb I still don't get it.

Comment: @xpaul Thanks for clarifying your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good answer is given for $a,b$ real. I don't think it holds for all complex numbers, but it might hold in some region of the complex plane. Please let me know if the following has any errors.

The inequality is equivalent to
$$|c^\alpha - 1| \leq |c-1|^\alpha.$$
Taking $c=|c|e^{i\theta}$ we can write this as
$$||c|^\alpha - e^{-i a \theta}| \leq ||c|-e^{-i \theta}|^\alpha$$
Choose $\alpha \theta = \pi$, $\alpha = 1/2$:
$$||c|^\alpha + 1| \leq ||c|-e^{-i \pi/a}|^\alpha$$

$$|c^{1/2}+1| \leq |c-1|^{1/2}$$

$$c+2c^{1/2}+1 \leq c-1$$
which can't be true for all $c$.

Comment: Sorry for my error above. $\alpha$ should be between $-1$ and $0$.

Comment: Yipe! Don't do that to me! ;-)

Comment: Okay, take $\alpha = -1/2$ in the answer I gave instead. Also, taking $\alpha \theta = \pi$ with $\alpha = 1/2$ isn't really fair, so just take a limit or something. I'm not up for making this clean.