# Proving that $|a(z)^\alpha - b(z)^{\alpha}| \rightarrow 0.$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

Related to an earlier question, I asked that [Is it true that $|a^{\alpha} - b^{\alpha}| \leq |a-b|^{\alpha}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205241/is-it-true-that-a-alpha-b-alpha-leq-a-b-alpha)

I was asking this since I am given that two functions $a(z)$ an $b(z)$ satisfy $|a(z)- b(z)| \rightarrow 0$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$, where $-1<\alpha<0$, and $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ lie on the upper-half plane of $\mathbb{C}$. I want to know whether $$|a(z)^\alpha - b(z)^{\alpha}| \rightarrow 0.$$ I wonder if we need to use uniform continuity of the power function in the upper half-plane (which I do not know how to show).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a(z) \to 0$. Then $b(z) \to 0$ and every thing is fine.

Otherwise, $\limsup a(z) > 0$. **Assume** more strongly that $|a(z)| \geq \delta>0$. I need to think more carefully otherwise. Perhaps in your case this is true. Then

$$|1-b(z)/a(z)| \cdot \delta \leq |a(z)| \cdot |1-b(z)/a(z)| $$
implies $b(z)/a(z) \to 1$.

But then we write

$$|a(z)|^\alpha |1-(a(z)/b(z))^\alpha| \leq \delta^{\alpha} |1-(a(z)/b(z))^\alpha|$$

which implies our desired limit goes to zero. It is very important here that $\alpha < 0$ otherwise $|a(z)| \geq \delta$ does not imply $|a(z)|^\alpha \leq \delta^\alpha$.

If $|a(z)| > \delta$ completely to begin with everything is fine. Hope this is enough for you without smooth edges.

Comment: so do you mean that my statement is true ? I don't want to publish something involving false results.

Comment: or is this only true if $|a(z)| > \delta$ for large $|z|$?